# How to Detect a Contract Creation by Another Contract in Ethereum?

Tags: ethereum

I'm working with smart contracts on Ethereum and I've encountered a challenge that I need help with.

I am interested in understanding how I can detect when a contract has been created by another contract. I understand that in Ethereum, a contract can create other contracts as part of its execution. This is an important aspect of my project and I'm having trouble finding resources that explain how to identify these contract creations.

Please check this tx: https://etherscan.io/tx/0x3322e04231dde2bad1fd876bc439661531b037e8bd308329768952246781dc62

In normal contract creation, the `to` is emtpy, so we can detect contract creation easily.

But above tx, the `to` is a contract address

So, my question is: how can one detect a contract creation by another contract in Ethereum? Are there specific event logs or transaction properties I should be looking for? And how do I track these events or properties?

Answer (score 1):

Contract is created with the `CREATE` and `CRATE2` opcodes.

Since each block stores only final state (e.g. storage changes and event logs) but not specific opcodes used during execution (or internal transactions that are separated between `*CALL` opcodes), you'll need to re-run and debug each block on your node, and look for the invoked opcodes.

---

Debug method on Go Ethereum node client: https://geth.ethereum.org/docs/interacting-with-geth/rpc/ns-debug#debugtraceblock

List of opcodes: https://ethereum.github.io/yellowpaper/paper.pdf, starts at page 30

Comment: I am still confused